# (C# WebBrowser) Why does "WebBrowser.Document" always returns null when reading PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf, webbrowser-control, textrange

It doesn't matter if it is in WPF or Winform, because I tried both and the results were the same.

I am making a PDF reader by using WebBrower.

First of all, I added the reference and the directive "using mshtml".
Then I loaded the PDf file like this:

```
       OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog() { Filter = "*.pdf(PDF file)|*.pdf" }; ;
        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate(dlg.FileName);
        }
```

Then I tried to search for a string in the WebBrowser, which did not work:

```
       if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
        {
            IHTMLDocument2 document = webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument as IHTMLDocument2;
            if (document != null)
            {
                IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = document.selection;

                IHTMLTxtRange range = currentSelection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
                if (range != null)
                {
                    const string search = "Privacy";//This string is in the PDF file;

                    if (range.findText(search, search.Length, 2))
                    {
                        range.select();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I also set a breakpoint at this line:

```
  IHTMLSelectionObject currentSelection = document.selection;
```

But the breakpoint was never triggered, which means the variable "document" is always null. Why is that? Do I have to set a document property for the WebBrowser? I can't figure out what causes the problem.

I want to search for a string and then highlight it.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't know the exact details, but I know if you told an IFrame in IE to navigate to a PDF it would create an instance of the web browser control and then create an activeX or object tag or some other mechanism for handling PDF.  As I understand it, IE/ web browser control does not handle PDF's natively instead it instantiates something else to handle it for it.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett Thanks for the reply. I did some research too, and ended up with the same conclusion as yours.